# What password should I pass when joining my Azure directory with samba

Tags: linux, ubuntu, samba, freeradius

I am on a task to deploy a radius server with Azure AD.

I've created my components needed and i've reached the following step:

Source: https://wiki.freeradius.org/guide/freeradius-active-directory-integration-howto
[image]

When I run this bash command i need to pass a password but i don't recall giving my user a password.
So what password am i supposed to pass here?

Thanks,
Ahune

Comment: You need credentials for an AD admin with permission to add new devices to the domain.

Comment: @Panki do you mean a User with role: admin in the AD directory. That explains it.

Comment: Kinda. Any domain admin should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

The password to pass is the Account with admin permission in the Azure Active directory (AAD) and also make sure to use the users username instead of using Administrator.

```
-U #user
net join -U <<Username>>
```

Thanks Panki